# PHP/SQL: Prevent Option values from repeating

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

So I am trying to create a query that shows the list of all the dates customers came in to order food. However, since there were multiple customers for a particular day and thats how the values have been stored in the table, whenever I turn the following query:-

```
SELECT DateOfEntry FROM KFC;
```

Although it works and I see all the details, I dont want the same date value to repeat. For example if Two customers A and B, came in on 11/11/17 to order food, I would get the result of the above mentioned query with two records of same date. I dont want the same dates to repeat. What do I do?
I know DISTINCT works but the problem is, I am creating a php page where admins can check the list of all the users who came in on a particular day. So I am using the select and option methods of HTML to select a date which then shows the list of the users who made an entry that day. With this code, only one record is shown

Comment: Post sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`SELECT DISTINCT DateOfEntry FROM KFC;`

Comment: It works but the problem is, I am creating a php page where admins can check the list of all the users who came in on a particular day. So I am using the select and option methods of HTML to select a date which then shows the list of the users who made an entry that day. With this code, only one record is shown.

Comment: I think you have two options here. Either you run the query to get everything, say:
`SELECT DateOfEntry, User from KFC`
and you filter on the client-side

Or you first show all the dates (with the query I put in the response) and then when a date is selected you run another query to get all the people for that day.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
      SELECT DISTINCT DateOfEntry FROM KFC;
```

or this

```
    SELECT DateOfEntry FROM KFC
    GROUP BY DateOfEntry;
```